# FormFactor has no effect on form size in Visual Studio Windows CE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I have configured a form factor with screen size 240x320:
[image]

I have made it the default form factor:
[image]

It has no effect:
[image]

I have recreated the project, restarted Visual Studio, Googled thoroughly, and am stuck.

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting WindowState to Maximised will magically resize the form to the dimensions specified by the selected FormFactor.

Comment: But it doesn't help with the designer. `WindowState` will default to 640x480 while maximised, changing this will have the window revert at a later time.

Answer (score 4):

The setting you're adjusting is for the default skin for the emulator.  It has nothing to do with the Form Designer (which you show in the last screen shot).  As far as I know, if your target type is set to "Windows CE" (as opposed to WinMo) when you add a new Form to the project, then you always get one that is 640x480.  This is similar to desktop projects where you always get the same sized Form when you create a new one.  You simply have to change it's size after you've added it to the project.

Comment: That's pretty stupid imo. If this is the case then at least it should be made clear so I don't get confused.

Comment: If this is the case, how do you set the form size when setting the state to `Maximized`? Resizing after changing `WindowState` causes the window to revert to the 640x480 size which is very annoying.

Comment: Just set the dimensions of the form in the designer, not the `WindowState`.  Set the `WindowState` in code in the ctor.